# cabal install cabal-install fails due "missing" installed-package

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I just updated the haskel-plataform did a cabal update and was informed there is a new version of cabal-install that I should update to. So I do a cabal install cabal-install and get:

```
cabal: The following installed packages are broken because other packages they
depend on are missing. These broken packages must be rebuilt before they can
be used.
package random-1.0.1.1 is broken due to missing package
base-4.5.1.0-47f48c3ae7f8256a66a23e9dfe22eefc
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.16.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The thing is that If I do cabal install random, I see that that version of random is already installed:

```
 => cabal install random
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
random-1.0.1.1
```

I am at a loss at what is the problem or how to fix it

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg check` report? And what version of base have you with the upgraded platform (`ghc-pkg list base`)?

Comment: Try doing `ghc-pkg unregister random` before a `cabal install random`

Comment: Daniel, here is the output, apparently I have a broken system: https://gist.github.com/PuercoPop/5332945

Comment: Hmm it appears to be that my previous homebrew instalation could be conflicting

Comment: Yes, looks like it's reading an old package database. The fix would be to delete some files/directories, maybe even reinstalling the platform is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I had did unregister for all the packages that referenced /usr/local/Cellar and it was successful. I had written a comment thanking you both but appparently it wasn't sent. So thank you both for your time